# Pandas create an intraday DateTimeIndex between 2 times each day excluding weekends and holidays

Tags: python, pandas

What I'm looking to generate I think is quite common. I basically want to create a DateTimeIndex over a long period (eg 1 year) which has a row for each 10min increment between 9 and 5 excluding times outside of that, weekends and custom holidays.

So far I have got:

```
rng = pd.date_range(start="2015-09-01 07:00", end="2015-11-15 17:30", freq="600S", tz="Europe/London")
rng = rng[rng.indexer_between_time('07:00','17:30')]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This list comprehension gets you weekdays between 7am and 5:30pm:

```
rng = [d for d in rng 
       if d.weekday() < 5 
       and d.hour >= 7 
       and d.hour < 18 
       and (False if d.hour == 17 and d.minute > 30 
            else True)
      ]
```

You need to create a list of dates for your holidays.  This tends to be location specific, so I'll leave this up to you.  Then just filter those dates.

```
holidays = [...]  # dates
rng = [d for d in rng if d not in holidays]
```

Then create your DateTimeIndex:

```
dt_idx = pd.DateTimeIndex(rng)
>>> dt_idx
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2015-09-01 07:00:00+01:00, ..., 2015-11-15 17:30:00+00:00]
Length: 10870, Freq: 10T, Timezone: Europe/London
```